# Transporting database from one platform to another platform in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

## Source Database Details:

Plat form : Windows 64 bit,
Database software version: 11.2.0.1

## Target Database details:

Plat form :Linux 32 bit,
Database Software Version: 11.2.0.3

My doubt is can we transfer entire database from windows o/s to Linux o/s or reverse by using RMAN transport tablespace concept?

or Is there any need to upgrade source database from 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.3 for successfully transport database ?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you must set the compatibility level on the target database to match the compatibility level on the source database. Here is a
master note link that covers some questions and answers:

```
https://blogs.oracle.com/db/entry/master_note_transportable_tablespaces_tts_--_common_questions_and_issues
```